# how to prevent multiple user input due to refreshes (Node JS)

Tags: node.js

I am quite new to web development itself. And I have a problem which I have no idea how to solve or even what to google. The web app is developed with Node JS and MySQL.

So let me explain the situation.
On my website you can create and delete posts.

1. On "/create", the user enters contents for the post.
2. Then the user clicks the "submit" button, which is routered to "/create_process"(where the data is actually saved in database)
3. Occasionally there is some delay in loading "/create_process". So the user keeps refreshing while loading. -> Here is the problem. Everytime the user refreshes at this stage same inputs are sent again and again. The result is multiple posts with exactly same contents.

   I am sure that there must be a way to block such trivial inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a throttle function on whatever the use is clicking. Example:

```
const throttle = (func, limit) => {
  let inThrottle
  return function() {
    const args = arguments
    const context = this
    if (!inThrottle) {
      func.apply(context, args)
      inThrottle = true
      setTimeout(() => inThrottle = false, limit)
    }
  }
}
```

from [medium article](https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf)